# Need help on NTLM signing over LDAP authentication

Tags: ldap, ntlm, signing, jcifs, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I need to do NTLM authentication over LDAP protocol. For this I am trying to use [Unbound ID LDAP SDK](https://github.com/pingidentity/ldapsdk) and [jcifs-ng](https://github.com/AgNO3/jcifs-ng) together. Everything works fine if domain controllers doesn't require LDAP signing (integrity check). If LDAP signing is enabled, code fails with message

> The server requires binds to turn on integrity checking if SSL\TLS are
> not already active on the connection

If I use NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN flag for Type3Message, code fails with following message ( even if LDAP Signing is disabled in domain controller )

> resultCode :: 49 (invalid credentials) resultCode :: 80090302:
> LdapErr: DSID-0C090588, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 1, v2580

Please point me to any other way or the mistake in my approach to construct Type3Message properly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NTLM signing was achieved using apache httpclient library instead of using jcifs-ng